# How to change the color of Visual Studio syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio

VS default color scheme is really tired of watching
like:

[image: Unity3d]

Comment: There are hundreds if not thousands of VS themes available at https://studiostyl.es/

Comment: @ZebRawnsley None work for VS2017

Answer (score 8):

All Visual Studio versions have this available here:

**Menu > Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors**

Recent versions of Visual Studio come with 4 built-in themes that can be changed from:

**Menu > Tools > Options > Environment > General**